# How to work with data from a select query on a mssql array

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I will first of all start by saying hello and that I am a beginner at MSSQL and PHP but I am constructing a project at work and need some guidance.

What I have at the moment is a working MS SQL database and a web page that will display data from this DB. The connection and the interaction is working at the moment and I can perform simple queries using PDO and get them to display using a PHP web page.

I think what I want to do should be quite simple, but don't know where to start asking, as I do not know the correct terminology yet and I'm quite open to places to look for help too =)

OK - So here is my issue:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT TOP 25 * FROM tonerDel ORDER BY tonerID DESC");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

Then I have a for each loop that displays data from this query. What I would like to do is play around with the data in this query.

In plain terms I wish to display one field from one column. The last tonerID in the list (the highest number) to display the total number of deliveries done by our company to date.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

I'm probably being stupid but have tried for 3 days now and I get nowhere. I did try a MAX function but the code displayed something along the lines of the driver does not support this.

Some sample data as requested (looks a bit messy as I removed the customer names):

```html
Last 25 deliveries:Total Deliveries:
5732 2017-04-20 LS4 KONICAC284 A4FK021014605
5731 2017-04-20 Ltd XEROX6605 3188473848
5730 2017-04-20  BD6 KONICAC280 A0ED022002354
5729 2017-04-20  XEROX6605 3188442977
5728 2017-04-20  T/A Whitegates OLIVMF222 A5C4321105153
5727 2017-04-20  KONICAC360 A0ED021004896
```

In this instance, I would like to retrieve the last tonerID which would be 5732 shown in line 1 above as this is the last delivery row entered as the SELECT query retrieves the last 25 deliveries in DESC order.

Comment: please provide some sample data and expected result

Comment: if tonerID is the only field you need then don't use * but use tonerID in your select command. If you only want the last one, then add LIMIT 1 to the end of your query

Comment: That's the issue, I wanted to save doing another separate query just to get a piece of data that I already had in the array. So the list above is displayed on the web page, then can you see where it says Total Deliveries: - I wanted the 5732 to be displayed there by grabbing it from the array somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a confusing question, but it sounds like you want to select the `tonerID` column, and select the last row within this column, which is the total number of deliveries.

To do this, you can use the MAX function like so:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT MAX(tonerID) as totalTonerID FROM tonerDel");
```

That query will essentially search the database for the highest number in tonerID, which should always be  your total.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Right, so I can't use the existing query, I have to do 2 separate ones? That was the question really, can I do two things with one query? Also, like I mentioned, the MAX function came back with an error but I will try it again now.

Comment: Flipping heck, finally got it to work thanks to your advice! Thank you very much, I'll post what I did below.